# $ ∑_{x∈X}|f(x)|<∞ \quad ⇔ \quad ∑_{i=1}^∞|f(x_i)|<∞ $

Tags: real-analysis

if $\mathbb{X} $ be a countable set i.e. $\mathbb{X}=\{x_1,x_2,x_3 ...\}$ and $$\sum\limits_{x∈X}|f(x)|=\sup \{\sum\limits_{x∈F}|f(x)|\quad F⊆X,|F|<∞\}$$ then show that

$$  ∑_{x∈X}|f(x)|<∞    \quad  ⇔ \quad  ∑_{i=1}^∞|f(x_i)|<∞ $$

$⇐) $It is obvious.

$⇒) $if   $\quad∑_{x∈X}|f(x)|<∞    \quad $
How do I prove that this is true for a number of non-countable ?

Comment: The sum on the left, is that defined as the supremum for all sums over finite subsets of $X$? Your notation is garbled up. Do the two different styles of $X$ mean something? What do sum over in the last sum, $x\notin X$? And where does non-countability enter the picture, when you started with a countable set? Finally, I don't know what you mean by “this Process” and the odd looking inequalities ($\cdots\ge\infty$) in the final box.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen  $∑_{x∈X}|f(x)|=sup ∑_{x∈F}|f(x)|\quad F⊆X,|F|<∞$

Answer (score 2):

**Outline**: For each $n$, let $X_n = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$. You first have that
$$
\Big\{ \sum_{x \in X_n} |f(x)| :n \in \Bbb{N}\Big\} \subset \Big\{ \sum_{x \in F}|f(x)| : F\subset \Bbb{X} \text{ is finite}\Big\}
$$
from which you can deduce that for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)| \leq \sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}} |f(x)| 
$$
from which the inequality
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |f(x_i)| \leq \sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}} |f(x)| \quad (1)
$$
follows.

On the other hand, assume that $\sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}}|f(x)| < \infty$. Take any $\epsilon > 0$ and let $F \subset \Bbb{X}$ be finite such that $$\sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}}|f(x)| - \epsilon < \sum_{x \in F} |f(x)|.$$ Since $F$ is finite, there is some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $F \subset X_n$ and so
$$\sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}}|f(x)| - \epsilon < \sum_{x \in F} |f(x)| \leq \sum_{x \in X_n}|f(x)|= \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x)|.
$$

You should be able to deduce from this that
$$
\sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}} |f(x)| - \epsilon \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |f(x)|.
$$

Comment: Thank you Tom.I have a question. Might be obvious, But can you please answer? inequality (1) how you obtained?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ast = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \ast$ (when the sum converges). So, since $\sum_{i=1}^n \ast \leq \sum_{x \in \Bbb{X}} \ast$ for every $n$, take the limit.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness